# php strpos always returning false,i want to get a right answer

Tags: php, strpos

I get a project and i see a piece of code as follows:

```
<?php
$orderby=$_REQUEST['orderby'];
if(strpos($orderby,'d')===true){
    echo "exists";
}else{
    echo "not ";
}?>
```

In any case , i input 'd' or others parameters the page always returning 'not'.
 so, how to input correct parameter make the page returning 'exists'?

Comment: When in doubt about how something works view the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php. See the `Return Values` section. You also can scroll down to user contributions `I lost an hour before I noticed that strpos only returns FALSE as a boolean, never TRUE`...`is a different beast then: strpos() === true since the latter will never be true.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strpos()` can never return `TRUE`. If the string is found it returns the position. If the string is not found it returns `FALSE`. So you should compare with `FALSE`, not `TRUE`.

```
if (strpos($orderby, 'd') === false) {
    echo "not exists";
} else {
    echo "exists";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test is not saying that it is returning `false`, just that `strpos()` never returns a value of a boolean `true`.  Instead it will return an integer with the position of the string found.  Normally the check would be

```
if(strpos($orderby,'d') !== false){
    echo "exists";
}else{
    echo "not ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if `strpos` finds a match, it won't give back `true` but the offset - so your `strpos($orderby,'d')===true` is never hit.

Try this:

```
<?php
$orderby=$_REQUEST['orderby'];
if($o=strpos($orderby,'d')===false){
    echo "not ";
}else{
    echo "exists at offset $o";
}?>
```

Comment: i can't to modify the code,must input a correct parameter to get the page return 'exists'.Is there any other way?